# Cordova plugin development - How to include .so libs correctly? - UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: cordova

I have added a set of external libraries in my plugin.xml file:

```
<lib-file src="src/jniLibs/armeabi/libNearBytes.so" arch="device" />
<lib-file src="src/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libNearBytes.so" arch="device" />
<lib-file src="src/jniLibs/mips/libNearBytes.so" arch="device" />
```

Build/compile is successful, however at runtime I get the following error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.tony.workshop-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64,
>   /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libNearBytes.so"

What is the correct process to insure that these shared object files are placed into the apk?

Answer (score 1):

Shared Objects are not supported.  Binary code must be compiled for the platform's architecture.

Assuming you are trying to use NearBytes, follow these instructions:
http://www.nearbytes.com/developer/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=477